Disable short multi-line string concatenation in Ruff
If I have an intentionally short multi-line string like this:
html += (
    '<p>Regards,</p>\n'
    '<p>Tom Cruise</p>\n'
)

Ruff will automatically reformat as:
html += '<p>Regards,</p>\n<p>Tom Cruise</p>\n'

because the concatenated line fits within my max line width.
I am looking for a the linter setting, not disabling the linter with #fmt: off ... #fmt: on.
Also note that I cannot add trailing commas to the multi-line string, within the parentheses, which does prevent the behavior in other situations, e.g. lists.

This question is similar to: Black formatter - Ignore specific multi-line code. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
